# What does this calligraphy by 張照 say?

Tags: character-identification

I can make out bits of this calligraphy, but not enough to [look up the poem](http://www.shicimingju.com). The first line (and the poet, which I assume is the last two characters) should suffice for the purposes of using a search engine to find the entire thing...

The calligraphy is by 張照 of the Qing dynasty. I particularly like his style of grass script, but have not managed to find many images of his calligraphy.

[Click here to see the image (279KB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKwml.jpg)

Comment: Magnetar, I replaced the image with a link that lets you see the image separately (in a new tab, for example). I thought that big image would be too long when scrolling down, and resizing it would make it harder to read it properly, so I chose that solution. Obviously feel free to rollback, but I thought this would help more to the readability of your question. :)

Comment: How about just resizing the image? Why do you edit so much!

Comment: I was divided about the edit. On the one hand, I sorta see the point -- on the other hand, I seldom click through on other stuff. The question got answered, that's the main thing. Now I know it off by heart. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to read such works if you don't get trained with calligraphy knowledge. For me, I could only read some characters in this work. I.e., I read "歸去嵩陽" in the last line, so I used this word and 张照 as key word to search more info on the internet, and I found this on "[baike.baidu.com](http://baike.baidu.com/view/3339882.htm)". xiecheng127 is right, and I would like to paste the traditional version, since they are really traditional characters.

> 自有僲*才自不知，十年常夢採華芝。西風動地黃雲暮，歸去嵩陽尋舊師。

*Actually, 仙 is also used in traditional system, and 僲 (or 僊, more standard) is another form in old times. Here, it seems that the 舛 part was replaced with 升. I think this happens in calligraphy (some characters look "wrong" in calligraphy when compared to the standard form).

If you want to see more his works, "[artist.artxun.com](http://artist.artxun.com/13022-zhangzhao/zuopin/)" may be a good site.

By the way, when searching on some Chinese topics, google is not as good as baidu 百度, though you will get more ads with 百度.

Comment: very nice answer. i like how you gave an explanation of the different variant forms of 仙. i knew it was used in traditional chinese, but i wasn't aware that 僲 was a variant!

Answer (score 3):

“自有仙才自不知、十年常梦采华芝、西风动地黄云暮、归去嵩阳寻旧师”——张照